# Pythonic way to prevent execution of functions for logging purposes

Tags: python, logging

Let's consider, for debugging purposes, we would like to log the result of `costly_metric()`:

```
logger.info("some function")
logger.debug(f"result of costly metric: {costly_metric()}"
```

We only ever need this result for debugging and due to the computing resource costs involved in calculating `costly_metric()` it should *not* be executed if we set log level > debug.

However, `logging`, of course will execute the statement and then just hide the result. Minimal example:

```
l = logging.getLogger("logger")
l.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def foo():
    l.debug(f"costly metric: {costly_metric()}")
    l.info("test")

def costly_metric():
    l.warning("costly metric executed")
    return 42
```

If we call `foo()` now, this will result in:

```
> WARNING:logger:costly metric executed
> INFO:logger:test
```

Thus, `costly metric: 42` is just hidden in the logger's output but the method `costly_metric()` still is getting executed.

In order to prevent this behavior, we could check for the level with an if statement:

```
def foo():
    if l.level <= logging.DEBUG:
        l.debug(f"costly metric: {costly_metric()}")
    l.info("test")
```

What would be the most pythonic way to resolve this issue?

Comment: see https://orbifold.xyz/logging-expensive.html

Answer (score 3):

The `logging` module is intended to be used with separate log *format* and log *content*.

```py
l.debug("costly metric: {}", costly_metric())
```

In order to defer evaluating not just the formatting, but also the content, a helper can be used:

```py
class LazyStr:
    """Lazily evaluate a callable when its result string representation is needed"""
    def __init__(self, call):
        self.call = call

    # only perform the call when ``str`` or ``repr`` is used,
    # e.g. as part of log formatting
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.call())

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.call())

    # allow format field syntax, e.g. ``{:7.2f}``
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return format(self.call(), format_spec)

l.debug("costly metric: {}", LazyStr(costly_metric))
```